# Building a metal detector to detect 3mm particles

Tags: coil, detector, metal, balanced

I am trying to build metal detector to
detect some stainless steel and copper and iron particles with size approximately 2~3 mm embedded on circular food product. Its diameter about 2 cm and width about 1 cm.

I tried many metal detector circuits with different coils but I can't reach this sensitivity.

I searched on the internet and found a technique called "balanced coil technology" that can detect very small particles.  Can someone with previous experience in this type of circuit help me?

Comment: What type of metal detector are you talking about? Beach-combing or something else? What type of metal are you trying to detect?

Comment: These particles are what? plastic? Food?

Comment: I want to detect some stainless steel and CU and iron particle with size approximately 2~3 mm embedded on  circular food product Its diameter about 2 cm and width about 1 cm

Comment: @AhmedTharwat this information is so important, you should probably add it to your question by editing it! How wet/conductive is the food product?

Comment: Product seems small enough to be transported directly through the center of small coils, that should be better for detecting smaller metallic objects.  Might also want to use two separate detector coils and systems, one optimized for for ferrous metals, and another optimized for non ferrous metals. That way both types can be detected with one pass through.

Comment: If this is for commercial food manufacturing there are likely detailed governmental requirements for such detection equipment. Requirements such as sensitivity, calibration, testing, certification, etc, perhaps even demanding the specific type of detection systems that must be used. Designing and using your own detection device may not be acceptable.

Comment: @AhmedTharwat This calls into mind diffraction and scattering theory going back at least to Rayleigh in 1871, but more particularly with Mie's exact solutions in 1908, Stratton's othrogonal spherical vector wave solutions in 1944, and perhaps still more appropriate here Aden's backscattering experiments published in 1951 in the Journal of Applied Physics. I think you may well be in a territory of cheap "home microwave" wavelengths, but I've not sat down to check, exactly. I'm just name-dropping and suggesting you study this on your own. Your *mm-particle* situation *screams* this area to me.

Answer (score 0):

[ThermoFisher describes balanced-coil detection:](https://www.thermofisher.com/blog/food/x-ray-inspection-vs-metal-detection/)

> "Most metal detectors use a balanced, three-coil system to detect small particles of non-ferrous and stainless steel. The coils are wound on a non-metallic frame, each parallel with the other. The center coil is connected to a high frequency radio transmitter. Coils on either side of the transmitter coil are receivers. As these two coils are identical and placed the same distance from the transmitter, they receive the same signal and produce an identical output voltage. When the coils are connected in opposition, the output is cancelled, resulting in a zero value.  When a particle of metal passes through the coils of a metal detector, the high frequency field is disturbed under one coil, changing the voltage by a few microvolts. The state of balance is lost and the output from the coils is no longer zero. It is this phenomenon that is used to detect metal."

You might also consider x-ray particle detection, since the particles might be too small, and embedded too deeply to detect electronically. Find a cooperative dentist who could see if these particles show in a test.